Can't disable package cleanup - Error in log
after updating from artifactory-oss:7.90.14 to artifactory-oss:7.98.8 we encounter following error each night at 00:06:

Failed to fetch package cleanup run statistics.
org.artifactory.rest.exception.MissingRestAddonException: This REST API is available only in Artifactory Pro (see: jfrog.com/artifactory/features). If you are already running Artifactory Pro please make sure your server is activated with a valid license key.

Related to https://jfrog.com/help/r/jfrog-platform-administration-documentation/cleanup-policies there should be a Retention Policies menu visible in the administration section - but it isn't.
How can I disable this policy / job to avoid this error every night?
EDIT:
$ curl -H "Authorization: Bearer $TOKEN" -X PUT "localhost:8082/artifactory/artifactory/api/cleanup/policies/…" 
{ "errors" : [ { "status" : 405, "message" : "" } ]

Also tried GET http://{host:port}/artifactory/api/cleanup/packages/policies to get a list of all policies, but that results in 404 - no matter how I try to call it.

Stop All Running Cleanup Policies API ?

Retention of course :)
Somehow it doesn't work:
$ curl -H "Authorization: Bearer $TOKEN" -X PUT "http://localhost:8082/artifactory/artifactory/api/cleanup/policies/runs/forceStopAll"
{
  "errors" : [ {
    "status" : 405,
    "message" : ""
  } ]

Also tried GET http://{host:port}/artifactory/api/cleanup/packages/policies to get a list of all policies, but that results in 404 - no matter how I try to call it.

Can you find a artifactCleanup.json somewhere in your installation? What's its content?

@Markus nope, no such file exists.

HTTP 405 is "Method not Allowed", This means your TOKEN is incorrect.

The token has the scope "applied-permissions/admin" but I still get 405 - no matter if I add the token into header or into basic auth
curl -X PUT -u :$TOKEN "http://localhost:8081/artifactory/artifactory/api/cleanup/policies/runs/forceStopAll"
curl -H "Authorization: Bearer $TOKEN" -X PUT "http://localhost:8081/artifactory/artifactory/api/cleanup/policies/runs/forceStopAll"
Both fails with 405. Is there any specific permission or token needed except regular admin permissions?

Sorry, I can only point you to Introduction to the Artifactory REST APIs and/or search result: disable package cleanup. After q quick read, those do not mention a HTTP405...., which is (only?) mentioned here: https://jfrog.com/help/r/artifactory-how-to-debug-artifactory-issues-based-on-http-status-codes/405-method-not-allowed

MIght it be related to the fact: "This REST API is available only in Artifactory Pro"
I mean, the documentation tells about PUT on this endpoint, but I get a 405 - seems strange.

The issue has been identified, and the fix will be included in the next patch. The release is scheduled to be available within the next two weeks. Please stay tuned for the update, and thank you for your patience!

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
